# Cocoa Touch - UISegmentedControl title is not working in IF/ELSE statement

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to write a basic DST converter. I have a segmented control with 3 choices, their titles (surprisingly) are Distance, Speed and Time. I have 2 input text fields and a calculate button, as well as 2 labels for each text field with the type of measurement required and it's units. Making a selection on the segmented control should update the view accordingly. The variables have all been declared as IBOutlets, @property, @synthesize, and the code sits in an IBAction method, which is connected to the segmented control. The following code does not work, am I missing something completely obvious? (NSLog shows the correct title)

```
NSString *choice;    
choice = [dstChoiceSegmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex: dstChoiceSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
    NSLog(@"Choice |%@|", choice);
    if (choice == @"Distance") {
        firstLabel.text = @"Speed:";
        firstUnitsLabel.text = @"kts";
        secondLabel.text = @"Time:";
        secondUnitsLabel.text = @"hrs";
        answerUnitsLabel.text = @"nm";
    } else if (choice == @"Speed") {
        firstLabel.text = @"Distance:";
        firstUnitsLabel.text = @"nm";
        secondLabel.text = @"Time:";
        secondUnitsLabel.text = @"hrs";
        answerUnitsLabel.text = @"kts";
    } else if (choice == @"Time") {
        firstLabel.text = @"Distance:";
        firstUnitsLabel.text = @"nm";
        secondLabel.text = @"Speed:";
        secondUnitsLabel.text = @"kts";
        answerUnitsLabel.text = @"hrs";
    }
```

Thanks for your help (and I hope it's not some silly error that is staring me right in the face)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare strings this way. You need to do:

```
[choice isEqualToString:@"Distance"];
```

But if I were you, I'd check for the indicies instead.

edit: To explain it further: what you're doing with `choice == @"Distance"` is comparing a pointer with a string, which will not work. You need to call the string objects comparing method as shown above.

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat. As I'm relatively new to programming, why is it better to check for the indicies (which I'm now doing) rather than whether the strings match?

Comment: It takes up less ressources to compare integers then it takes to compare strings and thus may be a little bit faster. You propably wouldn't feel the difference, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And that's 2 new things I've learnt so far today!